# Hi all! got this error on Linux— /dev/zram0: write error: Text file busy

Tags: linux

Suddenly a whole 4 gig disk appeared, I can not delete it--
Wiping /dev/zram0, pass 0 (21)
/dev/zram0: write error: Text file busy

did anyone have such a error? Thx!

Comment: Hi! Linux Fedora. you cannot remove the disc because Text file busy!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to have installed and enabled
[zram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zram):

> zram, formerly called compcache, is a Linux kernel module for creating a compressed block device in RAM, in other words a **RAM disk**, but with on-the-fly disk compression. The block device created with zram can then be used for swap or as general-purpose RAM disk. The two most common uses for zram are for the storage of temporary files (/tmp) and as a swap device. Initially, zram had only the latter function, hence the original name "compcache" ("compressed cache").

If you wish to get rid of it, according to the
[zramctl man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man8/zramctl.8.html),
the following commands will do it:

```
sudo swapoff /dev/zram0
sudo zramctl --reset /dev/zram0
```

Comment: Mister, thank you! problem solved! how did you know where to look for a solution?I  still did not understand where I got the disk from, and in memory I did not allocate 4 gigs on the frames.